# How link domain name to static IP?

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, ip, domain, static-ip

i have

- static ip provided by my ISP
- home server (ubuntu)
- registered domain

I need to link my ip to domain but my registerer requires from me two NS addresses. So how can I link my ip to domain?

Comment: Usually whatever regiatar you used to register the name will provide nameservers ... Then you can just point the domain to your static IP... If you are tring to run your own nameservers tho you need more static IPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every domain needs a couple of domain name servers (DNS servers) to provide authoritative (official, unquestionable) answers to DNS queries that come in for that domain. So when you register "example.com" and someone asks the DNS system, "what is the IP address for www.example.com?", that query comes to the authoritative DNS servers for that domain.

So, yes, you either need to set up a couple machines on static IP addresses running DNS server software such as ISC BIND (a.k.a. "named"), or you need to pay a DNS service provider to host the DNS service for your domain.